# Contact submit button redirects to blank .PHP url?

Tags: php, contacts, contact-form

I have a contact form that I would like to send to my email address at my domain. However, upon hitting the "Submit" button, the website gets redirected to the .PHP url where it gives me:

`HTTP ERROR 500: This page isn’t working "mywebsite.com" is currently unable to handle this request.`

No email is received and the header("Location: ") doesn't redirect. I am currently using Bluehost. You can find the form I'm working on at [acromojo.com/contact](https://acromojo.com/contact.html). I haven't added security yet, just trying to get the form to work first.

What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="contactform.php">

    <div><select name="projectType">
      <option value="0">Start A Project</option>
      <option value="1">General Inquiry</option>
      <option value="2">Collaborating</option>
    </select></div></br>
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" required>
    <input name="company" type="text" placeholder="Company / Organization"></br>
    <input name="phone" type="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address"></br>
    <input name="location" type="text" placeholder="Location">
    <select name="find">
      <option value="0">How did you hear about us?</option>
      <option value="1">Social Media</option>
      <option value="2">Search Engine</option>
      <option value="3">Referrals / Recommendations</option>
      <option value="4">Other</option>
    </select></br></br>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Please tell us a little about your project, timeline, and budget" row="4" required></textarea></br>
    <label>Sign me up for the latest news, events, and more
      <input name="newsletter" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">

</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = $_POST['projectType'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $find = $_POST['find'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $newsletter = $_POST['newsletter'];

    $headers = "From: $email";
    $txt = "You have received an e-mail from ".$name."\n\n"
      "Location: ".$location."\n"
      "Contact: ".$phone.", ".$email."\n"
      "Found from: ".$find."\n\n"
      .$message;

    mail("hello@acromojo.com", $subject, $txt, $headers);
    header("Location: contact.html?mailsent");
  }
```

Comment: Have you checked the PHP error logs?

Comment: Try to make a new PHP that sends a email with `mail` no matter what. Try to visit that PHP get the result and see if it send or not. If not, get the last error and see if there is any problem with the server's email setup. Reference [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#121163) if you're not sure.

Comment: As the first comment suggested, your error logs are your best friend in this scenario. Check your error logs and it should provide a good first step to solving your issue.  Are you sure that the code receiving the form is in the same directory and also named contactform.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer came to me after aaaaaa123456789 commented. I checked the error_log where it was returning:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"Location: "' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

**Fix:** "\r\n""Location: "

**To:** "\r\n Location: "